# How to convert a ctime() call to strftime()?

Tags: c

The man page for `ctime` says that POSIX.1-2008 marks this function (among some other ones, too) as obsolete and advises that `strftime` should be used instead. I'm wondering how the format string for `strftime` would look in order to get the same output as `ctime`.

The only thing I've got so far is `%a %b %_2d %T %Y%n`, but `%_2d` is a Glibc extension, and I'd like that to work on Windows as well.

Comment: Did you try `%2d` instead of `%_2d` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me `Fri Nov 09 10:35:46 2012` instead of `ctime`'s `Fri Nov  9 10:35:46 2012`. :(

Comment: Why is that important to you? There are more standard date formats than the one given by `ctime` and you might switch to use them instead.

Comment: It's important to me because the output of `ctime` is used in a file, which needs to be backwards-compatible, therefore changing the format of the date is not an option, sadly. Thanks for the output, though. :)

Comment: What about going for Cygwin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime):

> `c` - writes **standard date and time string**, e.g. Sun Oct 17 04:41:13 2010 (locale dependent)

Comment: `%c` isn't quite right, as OP would still need a locale-independent way to get "Sun" and "Oct".

Answer (score 1):

Try `%e` for day of the month without leading `0`.